# Can't get my USB-C to Display Port Adapter to work on new iMac; works on MacBook Pro

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, displayport

I bought a new 2017 iMac 27", but I still want to use my 4K monitor. I was using the monitor with my 2012 MacBook Pro just plugging in the mini-DP cable into a Thunderbolt 2 port.

I tried the "[All Smart Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017TZTMBG)" USB Type C to Mini DP adaptor, which advertised that it worked on the new MacBook Pro, but it didn't work on my iMac.

Does anyone know what adapter I can use to connect my new iMac to my 4K monitor?

Answer (score 1):

[Thunderbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)#Thunderbolt_3) is a "multiplexing" of several signals including DisplayPort so the signal already exists there.  You just need a [Thunderbolt to DisplayPort cable](http://radnex.us/Cable-Matters-USB-C-Display-Port-Cable-4K) that goes from USB-C to DisplayPort (or mini DisplayPort if necessary) and you will be able to connect your 4K monitor.